# Caliburn IScreen TryClose() memory leak

Tags: c#

I've just opened a bunch of View's and I closed them using the code `TryClose()` and it creates ginormous amounts of memory leak. May I ask is there another way I should be closing a view using Caliburn that doesn't cause memory leak?

Comment: How did you determine this memory leak?

Comment: I loaded up multiple views with a profiler.